# Are there numbers for the characters?

Tags: itemize

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,pifont,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,pifont,xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={\color{myblue}\Pifont{pzd}{\char36}}]
\item Sample text
\begin{itemize}[label={\color{green}\Pifont{pzd}{\char228}}]
  \item Sample text
  \item Sample text
  \begin{itemize}[label={\color{red!50}\Pifont{pzd}{\char127}}]
    \item Sample text
  \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In this code, `\char36`, how can I know the shape of a character by using numbers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Note that the `pifont` package provides `\ding{<number>}`, which is easier than using `\char`: for instance, `\ding{36}` is much shorter than `\Pifont{pzd}{\char36}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consult the package manual to check any symbols you want and their respective numbers. The pdf is here: [pifont – Access to PostScript standard Symbol and Dingbats fonts](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf)

[image]